# A sequence that diverges to negative infinity

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

For a sequence that is unbounded and increasing, c>0, but why would it be the case that for a sequence that is unbounded and decreasing, c is c>0?

Comment: Because $-c$ is then negative (as in the definition you give in your question, which uses $-c$ in the second line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition uses a positive $c$ but states that $x_{n} < -c$, thus it's exactly the same thing as taking a negative $c$ and stating $x_{n}<c$.

Comment: I assume it's basically applying a minus operator to both side of the inequality and flipping the inequality in the other direction?

Comment: The definition says "no matter how 'close to $-\infty$'  a number is $A$, after a while all $x_n$'s are below this negative number". Note that for $A<0$ we have $A=-\lvert A\rvert$, and the closer $A$ is to $-\infty$ the bigger $\lvert A\rvert>0$ is: the definition you give in your question basically takes $c=\lvert A\rvert$.

Comment: Thank you. This was what I had in mind although I wasn't sure why it wouldn't be explicitly mentioned by the author of the notes (c=|c|).